# How to center rotated text in table with figures

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment

I'm trying to center the 2015 and 2016 labels in the left column of my table with figures:

```
\begin{figure}[htb]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{c c c}
& Juvenile salmon & High density \\
\multirow{2}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{2015}} & \includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{figure1.pdf} &
\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{figure2.pdf} \\
\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{2016} & \includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{figure3.pdf} &
\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{figure4.pdf} 
\end{tabular}
\caption{This is all the schools characteristics plots.}
\end{figure}
```

I don't know why they show up at the bottom instead of being centered with the figures... Any help very much appreciated!

[image: Example figure]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Things (boxes) are lined up horizontally by their baselines.  The rotated box has its baseline in the center, but the images have their baselines at the bottom.

I take it that the multirow was either an experiment or a mistake.  Anyway, trying to use multirow with images is difficult at best (non-standard spacing).

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{c c c}
& Juvenile salmon & High density \\
\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{2015} & \raisebox{-0.5\height}{\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{example-image-a}} &
\raisebox{-0.5\height}{\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{example-image-b}} \\
\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{2016} & \raisebox{-0.5\height}{\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{example-image-c}} &
\raisebox{-0.5\height}{\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{example-image}}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]